# How can I use angular.element instead of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How can I use `angular.element` instead of jQuery (`$`) for this block of code?

```html
<form style="display: none" action="{! $page.FormMigrateDownload}" method="POST" id="jsonDownloadForm">
  <input type="hidden" id="appFormJsonData" name="appFormJsonData" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" id="jsonFileName" name="jsonFileName" value="" />
</form>
```

```js
$scope.download = function(form) {
  $("#appFormJsonData").val(JSON.stringify(form));
  $("#jsonFileName").val('"TX-' + form.Name + '.json"');
  $("#jsonDownloadForm").submit();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like

```
> angular.element('#appFormJsonData').val(); OR
> angular.element('#appFormJsonData')[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome on StackOverflow

`angular.element` is simply a wrapper for `jQuery` (or `jqLite` if you didn't install jQuery) so you can use it as if you were using jQuery.

Read more in the [API docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) of AngularJS